# In what folder does Ngnix gets installed in Ubuntu Server

Tags: 12.04, server, nginx

I'm trying to understand the Nginx folder structure.

In what folder (or folders) does Ngnix gets installed in Ubuntu Server?

Thanks

Comment: See http://brajeshwar.com/2008/filesystem-file-organization-in-linux/ and also `sudo updatedb && locate nginx`

Answer (score 3):

To get a list of all files installed by a package use:

> dpkg -L `PACKAGE_NAME`

Note that this command will not list files installed by dependencies.

For example running `apt-get install nginx`  installs `nginx`, `nginx-core`, `nginx-common`. So you would have to run `dpkg -L PACKAGE_NAME` for each of these packages to get a list of all files that were installed by the `apt-get install PACKAGE_NAME` command.

The installed dependencies can be found with `apt-cache show PACKAGE_NAME` or by searching for `PACKAGE_NAME` in `/var/log/apt/history.log`.

Comment: yes, but that does not really explain the linux file system tree ;)

Comment: Con someone explain what the `sudo updatedb && locate nginx` shows? It show a lot more folders than `dpkg -L nginx` but they seem to be related to Nginx, what are they?